# Necesito contornear figura con color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis pasa del contorno necesito arreglarlo. Os dejo los códigos aquí: https://codepen.io/jaaddi1819daw2/pen/NEPqRm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice algunos cambios y ahora funciona. ¿En que te habías equivocado?:

`let input_color = document.querySelector("[type='color']")` selecciona al primer elemento cuyo `type` es `color`. para seleccionar el segundo necesitas `let input_color2 = document.querySelectorAll("[type='color']")[1];`

Al hacer click en un input type="color" tienes que cambiar el valor del relleno o del borde, según el input en el cual haces click, pero cada vez tienes que pintar la figura.

Además he visto que querías `ctx.fillStyle = el_color` y `ctx.strokeStyle = el_color2` dentro de la función que dibuja el polígono.

```js
  let miLienzo = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  let Figuras = document.getElementById("Figuras");
  let lapiz = miLienzo.getContext("2d");
  let cw = (miLienzo.width = 350),
    cx = cw / 2;
  let ch = (miLienzo.height = 200),
    cy = ch / 2;

  let R = 100;
  let el_color = "#ff0000";
  let el_color2 = "#00ff00";
  //lapiz.fillStyle = el_color;
  //lapiz.strokeStyle = el_color2;
  

  let lados = 0;
  
  
  let input_color = document.querySelectorAll("[type='color']")[0];
  input_color.value = el_color;
  input_color.addEventListener("input", actualizar1, false);
  //input_color.addEventListener("change", actualizar2, false);
  input_color.select();
  //Aqui finaliza el relleno interior de la figura

  //Aqui comienza el contorno de color el segundo input type color
  
  
  let input_color2 = document.querySelectorAll("[type='color']")[1];
  input_color2.value = el_color2;
  input_color2.addEventListener("input", actualizar2, false);
  //input_color2.addEventListener("change", actualizar2, false);
  input_color2.select();

  //$("#Figuras").on("change", 
Figuras.addEventListener("change",
function() {
    lados = Figuras.value;
    pintarFigura(lados, lapiz);
  });

  function pintarFigura(lados, ctx) {
    
    if(lados){
    clearCanvas();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    if (lados != "rect") {
      //Sino es un rectangulo entra aqui
      if (lados == 4) {
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
        dibujarPoligono(lados, ctx);
        ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 4);
      } else {
        //Si es un rectangulo dibujalo
        dibujarPoligono(lados, ctx);
      }
    } else {
      dibujarRectangulo(ctx, 200, 100);
    }
    ctx.restore();}
  }

  function clearCanvas() {
    lapiz.clearRect(
      -miLienzo.width,
      -miLienzo.height,
      2 * miLienzo.width,
      2 * miLienzo.height
    );
    lapiz.beginPath();
  }

  function dibujarPoligono(L, ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < L; i++) {
      x = R * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / L * i - Math.PI / 2);
      y = R * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / L * i - Math.PI / 2);
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.fillStyle = el_color;
    ctx.strokeStyle = el_color2;

    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  function dibujarRectangulo(ctx, w, h) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.fillStyle = el_color;
    ctx.strokeStyle = el_color2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h);
    ctx.strokeRect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h);
  }

  function actualizar1(event) {
    el_color = event.target.value;
    pintarFigura(lados, lapiz);
  }
  function actualizar2(event) {
    el_color2 = event.target.value;
    pintarFigura(lados, lapiz);
  }
```

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
font-family: 'Open sans';
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
.contenedor{
width:360px;
height:300px;
display:block;
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid

}
p{margin:1em;}

canvas{border:2px solid black;}

#Figuras{
font-size: 1em;
}
h1{
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<h1>APRENONLINE</h1>
<div class="contenedor">
<p><select id="Figuras">
<option>
Seleccione su figura
</option>
<option value="100">
Círculo
</option>
<option value="3">
Triángulo
</option>
<option value="4">
Cuadrado
</option>
<option value="rect">
Rectángulo
</option>
<option value="5">
Pentágono
</option>
<option value="6">
Hexágono
</option>
<option value="8">
Octágono
</option> 

<option value="cubo">
Cubo
</option>
<option value="esfera">
Esfera
</option>
<option value="cono">
Cono
</option>   
<option value="piramide">
Pirámide
</option> 
<option value="cilindro">
Cilindro
</option> 

</select></p>
    <label>Relleno: </label>
    <input type="color">
    <label>Contorno: </label>
    <input type="color">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="">    
</canvas>
  </div>
```

Espero que sea útil.

Comment: Duda resuelta respuesta aceptada!! Gracias de nuevo @enxaneta!!

Comment: tengo una duda con el código me podrías echar un cable?

Comment: En donde sale $ osea el principio $function esta hecho con jQuery y necesitaria poder pasarlo todo a Javascript puro las partes que faltan pero me pierdo me podrías hechar un cable. Gracias de verdad

Comment: @InfoTipsconJavitoBCN He actualizado el código y ahora lo tienes en vainilla. De hecho hice muy pocos cambios. Casi todo queda igual. Solo lo he sacado de dentro del bloque `$function`. Si lo quieres todo dentro de un  bloque de código lo puedes poner dentro de `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {`. . . `});`

Comment: perdón por la demora estuve fuera, muchas gracias !

Comment: tengo una duda a la hora de por ejemplo ponerlo todo en una carpeta en archivos separados el resultado no es el esperado y tengo todos los archivos bien linkados sabes a que se puede deber. Desde codepen lo veo bien pero si lo hago aparte linkando las rutas se ve mal sabes el porque?

Comment: Me pinta el canvas en el centro pero al seleccionar del select no me hace absolutamente nada ni los colores van ... Nose el porque... @enxaneta

Comment: No se que decir. Si funciona en codepen pero no en tu ordenador debe ser la estructura de ficheros. Que error te sale en consola?

Comment: osea tengo todo en una carpeta te pongo los archivos tal y como los tengo en otro codepen y miras a ver que puede pasar

Comment: Te dejo el link de codepen para que te bajes el codigo de cada archivo. Les he llamao index.html index.css y index.js y mira a ver si desde una carpeta aparte yo lo tengo en el escritorio y me esxtraña mucho. https://codepen.io/jaaddi1819daw2/pen/mQpWwj Con todo los codigos bien y linkados

Comment: lo he resuelto poniendo el <script> justo al final del html

Comment: Tengo otra duda que parámetros hay q pasarle al cubo por ejemplo para dibujarRectangulo son esos pero para el cubo como seria... function dibujarRectangulo(ctx, w, h) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.fillStyle = el_color;
    ctx.strokeStyle = el_color2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h);
    ctx.strokeRect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h);
} Tengo todo el codigo del cubo hecho pero no se como ponerlo

Answer (score 0):

Podrías agregar lo siguiente a tu función que dibuja los polígonos para dibujar el contorno:

```
ctx.strokeStyle=$("input[type='color']:eq(1)").val();
ctx.lineWidth=5;
ctx.stroke();
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: @ Gustavo Cantero En que parte en concreto porque no me funciona poniendo las lineas todavia

Comment: Ponelo en la función dibujarPoligono justo antes del ctx.fill().

Comment: Cierto funciona pero solamente en color negro y yo lo quiero dinamico como el otro input type color

Comment: Puedes cambiarle el color en la propiedad strokeStyle para establecer el color.

Comment: Pero he de realizar el mismo proceso que con el otro color y hay muchas mas lineas pero lo hago y no me lo aplica como el otro y eso no se como hacerlo

Comment: Ya modifiqué el código para que tome el color del segundo input color.

Comment: Ya lo vi las modificaciones pero sigue sin funcionar todavía esta que no tira algo hay que no le gusta

Comment: Acabo de probarlo en el Link que pasaste y funcionó bien.

Comment: Tal y como está ahora solo sigue saliendo en negro el contorno

Comment: Pon el link que te funciona a ti postálo aquí a ver si es la caché o algo

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXEWzp

Comment: Ya lo he probado y bien que se dibuja la figura y todo al aplicarle el color sale el color en el icono seleccionado pero no se aplica.

Comment: Si de verdad se cambia el color postea una captura conforme se cambia he probado mil formas y de verdad que no se cambia gracias de antemano.